# rstudio dbi odbc connect Driver for SQL Server

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

running the following code:

```
library(DBI)
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                  database = "xyz",
                  server = "abc",
                  Trusted_Connection = "yes")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("odbcListObjects") : 
  no applicable method for 'odbcListObjects' applied to an object of class "Microsoft SQL Server"
```

any idea?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time reproducing this, I'm able to connect to my SQL Server without problem. I can't trigger it with a typo in `driver=`, nor with an incorrect server (or port). I can't immediately test the `Trusted_Connection=` part, are you able to connect removing that arg and adding `uid=` and `pwd=`? (Not necessarily meant for a permanent solution, just feeling out the problem-space.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been [addressed in the dev version of the package](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/748#event-11556908938) and will be fixed in the next release of odbc. In the meantime, you can install the dev version with `devtools::install_github("r-dbi/odbc")`.

Comment: I restarted the session and it works now.