# Issue interacting via dbplyr with remote SQL tables probably since odbc or DBI or dbplyr package update

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, dbplyr

I used to have a R code working fine a few months back, which was connecting remotely to a SQL DB and interacting with it via dbplyr package.
Recently, I had to reinstall R/RStudio with all packages. Since then, I am no longer able to execute my script properly.

I am getting the following error when connecting:

```
Error in UseMethod("odbcListObjects") : 
  no applicable method for 'odbcListObjects' applied to an object of class "Microsoft SQL Server"
```

Meanwhile, it seems to partially work, as I am able for instance to list via `DBI::dbListTables()`, but I am no longer able to interact via `dplyr::tbl()`.

My problem appears similar to this SO issue [rstudio dbi odbc connect Driver for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847393/rstudio-dbi-odbc-connect-driver-for-sql-server) but installing the dev version of odbc or reverting to DBI 1.1.3 & odbc 1.4.1 did not work. I unfortunately don't know what package versions I had at the time.

Anyone has an idea of what may have changed within last 1,5 years regarding this packages which could explain such behavior/error?

Replicate of my code:

```
  con2 <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                        driver = "SQL Driver",
                        server = "my_server.com",
                        database = "my_db",
                        encoding = "latin1"
  )
tbl(con2, in_schema("schema", "table"))
```

Comment: Have you made sure to restart R after installing the various package versions? Could you try loading the odbc package with `library(odbc)` before attempting to connect? The linked issues in the related SO post should address the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I reinstalled the dev version of odbc between two computer restarts to be sure, and indeed it now works. I may not have restarted R on my first attempt yesterday. Thanks @Simon Couch. That may be worth keeping my SO question, or adding this detail to the other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found by @Simon Couch ; however answering my own question as it could help others, awaiting for Simon to do his own:

Installing the dev version of odbc indeed fixed the problem: it is required to restart R after installing the packages.